# iOS 11 - UINavigationItem titleView when using Large Titles mode

Tags: ios, navigationbar, ios11, uinavigationitem, titleview

I'm trying to understand either it's a bug or it's the expected behavior.

On **iOS 10** and earlier we could set up a custom title, using `navigationItem.titleView`.
On **iOS 11**, when setting our `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always` and setting `navigationItem.titleView = <Some cool UIButton>` it's displaying **both** the normal navigation title bar and the large navigation title.

Illustration:
[image]

To sum up:

**How can we use custom titleView on our Large Navigation Title?**

**EDIT : This is the expected result:**

[image]

Comment: "How can we use custom titleView on our Large Navigation Title?" You're doing it. That's the whole point! Previously, you could not have both a title and a title view. Now you can. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: @matt I understand that. But I'm looking for the option to change the large title using custom views. Updated the expected result

Comment: Well, stop expecting that result!  You’ve misunderstood this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replace the navigation bar big title with a custom view by using a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and manually changing the view hierarchy :

```
@interface MYNavigationBar : UINavigationBar

@end
```

```
@implementation MYNavigationBar

// ...

- (void)layoutIfNeeded
{
    [self setupTitle];
    [super layoutIfNeeded];
}

- (void)setupTitle
{
    // UINavigationBar
    // -> ...
    // -> _UINavigationBarLargeTitleView
    //   -> UILabel << Big Title Label
    //   -> UIView
    //     -> UILabel << Big Title Label animating from back button during transitions

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder);
        if ([className containsString:@"LargeTitleView"]) {
            for (UIView *view2 in view.subviews) {
                if ([view2 isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                    [self convertLabel:(UILabel *)view2];
                }
                for (UIView *view3 in view2.subviews) {
                    if ([view3 isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                        [self convertLabel:(UILabel *)view3];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)convertLabel:(UILabel*)label
{
    // I kept the original label in the hierarchy (with the background color as text color)
    // and added my custom view as a subview. 
    // This allow the transformations applied to the original label to be also applied to mine.
}
```

Please note that Apple *might* reject your app because of this trick.

Comment: Altho it might cause rejection, it's a great answer! Anyway seems like Apple won't change the private class names so quick, and if the UI looks good I bet they won't ever care. Great job!

Comment: Want to know if you are able to submit the application to appstore with this change as the class name is private

Comment: I had no issue during the review however I can’t say it 100% safe

Answer (score 6):

I can't find any documentation on this, so I played a bit. It seems in iOS 11, you won't be able to get that title to be a button and display large at the left.

I don't know if this is a bug or the expected result, as it seems to be a new feature. The latest (iOS 11) [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/bars/navigation-bars/) (HIG) discuss the larger title label as being a way to give the user clear context. The HIG also discuss space between buttons. However, there's no discussion of using a button *as* the title.

---

To recreate, I set up a Single View project. I embedded the view controller in a navigation controller.

In `ViewController.swift`'s `viewDidLoad`, I added this code:

```
    let titleButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
    titleButton.setTitle("Hello Button!", for: UIControlState.normal)

    let navController = parent as! UINavigationController

    navController.navigationBar.topItem!.title = "Hello???"
    navController.navigationBar.topItem!.titleView = titleButton
    navController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

This ends up looking something like your example.

**IF I**:

- set `.title` to empty string, or remark the line out: navbar is stretched, and no title text shows (or title text set in Interface Builder shows)
- remark out `.prefersLargeTitles`, or set it to `false`: the navbar is the normal height, the button displays, but no title text displays.
- remark out the `titleView` line, AND:

  - leave the `.prefersLargeTitles` set to `true`: the `title` text displays large at the left, and the navbar's height is stretched.
  - set the `.prefersLargeTitles` to `false`: the `title` text displays in the top center, and the navbar is normal height.

**Update:** link to [sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/leanne63/UINavigationBarTitleDemo)

Comment: Hey Leanne, nice investigation. So as far as I understand, it's impossible to achieve clickable large title? :\

Comment: That’s what it looks like. You might try [reporting it as a bug to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to see what they say. Feel free to link to my example as a demo, or fork it if you’d like to add more info of your own.